# Postman - Looping through an array of nested objects to make a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, testing, postman

I am trying to set a variable from following phone number with value: **“+33652556777”** (index 4 in JSON attached below) which is the last object in contacts (index 4).

To do so is pretty simple:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
console.log (jsonData.contacts[4].phone_numbers[0].value)  
const PhoneNumber = jsonData.contacts[4].phone_numbers[0].value
pm.environment.set("Jacky", PhoneNumber);
```

Since I have to use different query parameters to filter by eg. **created_at=asc, desc,** the property of the **phone_numbers** order might change index number and I won’t be able to fetch desire phone number "+33652556777” instead it will set a different phone number which I cannot allow.

I know there is way to fetch our number and make it variable for next requests, which is iterating over properties or keys in the object “ **for….in or for…of** ” but for some reason I cannot achieve it.

What I could achieve is to get through first object “contacts” but impossible to get to its nested array “phone_numbers”. Here is how I did it:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let contact;
for (let filter of jsonData.contacts){
if (filter.last_name == "Rowland"){
   contact = filter;
}} 
console.log (contact);
```

Could you please help?

Here goes the JSON body response:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 11121211,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "test1",
      "last_name": "test",
      "company_name": "test",
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1582798926,
      "updated_at": 1582798926,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 60065270,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567666"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 22222222,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company_name": null,
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686067,
      "updated_at": 1583686067,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 22266444,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567899"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 33333564,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "Jessica",
      "last_name": "Biel",
      "company_name": "N-Sync",
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686086,
      "updated_at": 1583686086,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": []
    },
    {
      "id": 45678901,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company_name": null,
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686105,
      "updated_at": 1583686105,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 22266444,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567333"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 56789123,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "Jacky",
      "last_name": "Rowland",
      "company_name": "Test Company1",
      "information": "",
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583745888,
      "updated_at": 1608556499,
      "emails": [
        {
          "id": 76594398,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "mandatory_field@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 60650277,
          "label": "Mobile",
          "value": "+33652556777"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "count": 6,
    "total": 241,
    "current_page": 1,
    "per_page": 5,
    "next_page_link": "https://example.example",
    "previous_page_link": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use forEach or _.each as danny mentioned to get all numbers else use:

```
console.info(jsonData.contacts.find((a)=>a.first_name==="Jacky").phone_numbers[0].value)
```

use array.find to find the contact with first_name jacky adn then get phone_number[0].value from it.

if you want all numbers from that array then use:

```
console.info(jsonData.contacts.find((a)=>a.first_name==="Jacky").phone_numbers.map((a)=>a.value))
```

here we map the result to get only the numbers from phone_number array.

is it what you looking for !?

Comment: Multiple different ways to do the same thing. Might need to modify your answer to push that into a variable, as the was the original reason, rather than writing it to the console.

Comment: No worries, after checking the log in the console it all made sense and I was able to set my variables. Thanx again

Answer (score 2):

You could use something basic like this:

```
_.each(pm.response.json().contacts, (contact) => {
    if(contact.last_name === "Rowland") {
        pm.environment.set(`${contact.first_name}_${contact.last_name}_number`, contact.phone_numbers[0].value)
    }
})
```

There are probably better and more performant ways to do this but if you just want to set a variable for that contact, no matter where they are in the response - This would work :D